# Reason for dupe closing seems invalid

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

My question [How to remove glue from temporary paper shades on vinyl windows?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/245135/87590) was just closed as being a duplicate of [what is the easiest way too clean adhesive residue from glass?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/24494/87590)

However my question was specifically about residue on the Vinyl part of the window and not the glass.  These are two totally different surface types and definitely require different approaches when working with them. (EG I'm not going to take a razor blade scraper to my vinyl windows)

Aside from generalities of residue removal, about the only similarity I can see between the two questions is that in one of the answer in each question is that a chemical remover like "Goof-off" or "Goo Gone".  However the person who suggested "Goo-Gone" for removal from the vinyl also used the caveat that it "*should*" be safe for Vinyl usage.

With that said, am I correct in my belief that the reason for closing my question as a dupe is unreasonable?

And finally @Freeman suggested in a comment that my question also falls into a potential closing as a "product recommendation" question.  I was trying very hard not ask for an explicit product recommendation, but I am not sure how you can ask a question about a specific set of circumstances without specific products being suggested as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure how you can ask a question about a specific set of circumstances without specific products being suggested as an answer.

From your question:

> And I am looking for products in the USA

That's going to trigger people to VTC. If you're looking for a technique to clean, or ingredients in a cleaner (e.g. dish soap, vinegar, bleach, etc aren't product recommendations they way name brands are) that might be more on topic, but the question needs to be rephrased for that. See other questions on the site that focus on what tool, rather than which brand of what tool, they need to solve an issue.

The question itself also skirted around the problem being on the Vinyl part of the frame. I'd put that up front in the question rather than leaving it ambiguous with "the glue itself remained". A picture would also help avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: I thought I was being explicit when I mentioned twice (actually 3 times :) ) that the residue was on the vinyl part of the window.  In hindsight your comment about "products in the USA" is fair, but in my defense I only added that after being explicitly asked by @Milwrdfan's  where in the world I was.  Perhaps I should have worded that as "solutions easily available in teh USA"

Comment: Also the actual VTC was not a "shopping question" reason

Comment: In the timeline, you received 2 close votes for the duplicate question before making the clarification. And then a 3rd close vote for being a product recommendation after your update. The system just shows the most popular reason people had for the VTC, and voters can't change their reason (they can retract, but once done, they can't VTC again).

Comment: I doubt I'll ever have the rep on here to see the actual VTC count, but I made the assumption that the VTC was unanimous.  Hopefully my new edits will help things out.